# Calling a function from child component, but it is repeatedly being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call a function that is 2 levels up from my child component (as this will refresh the data sent down in props to my child).

However, the problem I am facing is that the function getBooking is being constantly called. It should only be called once when the form submits in the child component, so not sure how it's being repeatedly called.

Grandparent:

```
const getBooking = async (fullReload: boolean) => {
  ...code
}

<BookingGuestList
   getBooking={getBooking(false)}
/>
```

Parent:

```
<GuestListRow
   getBooking={getBooking()}
/>
```

Child:

```
getBooking();
```

Comment: `getBooking={getBooking(false)}` This means "call getbooking(false) immediately, and pass its return value into the prop". You probably meant to do `getBooking={() => getBooking(false)}`

Comment: It should be `getBooking={() => getBooking()}` and `getBooking={() => getBooking(false)}` instead

Comment: Thank you guys!!! I think I finally get react now haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the parent function in the following way

Child:-

```
getBooking={()=> getBooking()}
```